# How to delete data according to certain criteria in R

Tags: r, criteria

I want to delete datapoints if their value are above a certain value but below another, but I simply cannot figure out how to do it in R.

I want to remove data points if x<0.5 and y>2, but both criteria needs to be met.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(100,0,2), y=runif(100,1,4))
todrop <- which(dat$x <0.5 & dat$y>2)
dat <- dat[-todrop,]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working. Only data for which both criteria (i.e. x<0.5 and y>2) are met should be removed - any idea about how to do that? thanks!!

Comment: @R-gal please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Show some code and tell us "what actually is not working"

Comment: Thanks Beasterfield, I'm new in this, sorry. I have a dataset with 500 datapoints, where I want to remove some of them because they are obviously wrong. I have tried both suggestions, but they remove too many points, i.e. they remove ALL points where x<0.5 even though the criteria for y isn't met. Does it make sense? Will try to post the codes I used as well..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this programmatically, the use of `subset` should be avoided (see [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) for details).

Instead, you could go with the `data.frame` syntax:

```
dat[ dat$x >= 0.5 & dat$y <= 2, ]
```

Reading of `? "[.data.frame"` is an absolute must to any R beginner.